# how to calculate the final out print number in this program?

Tags: java

This is a practice program from the textbook. I need to figure out the out print for this program.
Here's the program:

```
public class EchoTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();

        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            e1.hello();
            e1.count = e1.count + 1;
            if (x == 3) {
                e2.count = e2.count + 1;
            }
            if (x > 0) {
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x = x + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}
```

---

```
class Echo {
    int count = 0;

    void hello() {
        System.out.println("helloooo... ");
    }
}
```

The answer of the out print for this program is:

```
helloooo...
helloooo...
helloooo...
helloooo...
10
```

I don't quite understand how this calculate in main. It seems like x cycled for 4 times. x=0; x=1;x=2; x=3. And e1 should have value 1,2,3,4 because e1.count=e1.count+1.
Then I confused, how can I calculate e2 in this case?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Can you post your expected result.

Comment: Best way to undestand is to debug the code in IDE. If not write to console, the values inside the while loop to see how the loop executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observed variable output

```
public class EchoTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();

        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            e1.hello();
            e1.count = e1.count + 1;
            System.out.println("e1.count = " + e1.count);
            if (x == 3) {
                e2.count = e2.count + 1;
                System.out.println("x == 3 e2.count = " + e2.count);
            }
            if (x > 0) {
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
                System.out.println("x > 0 e2.count = " + e2.count);
            }

            x = x + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! But why e2 only out print the last cycle value , which is 10?

Comment: Never mind! I got this!

Answer (score 0):

Make up a table of x, e1.count, and e2.count.  Then just follow along with the program and update the values line by line.  I get 10 for e2.count's final value.  e2.count stays at 0 for x=0.  But it gets an extra increment at x=3.